# How do I use Infinite AJAX Scroll on a landscape page?

Tags: jquery-ias

How do I use Infinite AJAX Scroll (http://infiniteajaxscroll.com/docs/overview.html) on a landscape page?

Comment: You mean horizontal scrolling?

Comment: Yes, that's right, did not express myself well

Answer (score 0):

Infinite Ajax Scroll is not designed for horizontal scrolling pages and can't be used for such an use-case.